# Find χ(G) (Chromatic number of the graph)

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let G be a graph with vertex set V = {1, . . . , 20} Vertices u, v ∈ V are adjacent if and only if gcd(u, v) = 1. Find χ(G) and explain your answer.

I couldn't finish this answer all the way, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you add details about some of your attempts to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $9$.

$u, v \in V$ being adjacent if and only if $\gcd(u, v) = 1$ is equivalent to saying that $u$ and $v$ are not connected provided that they share a non-trivial common factor.

In particular, we can color all vertices that are multiples of $2$ with one common color since they will share a common factor (and so, they won't be directly connected). Among the remaining numbers, we can paint the multiples of $3$ a second color since they will share a common factor. Continuing in this fashion, we end up requiring exactly one color for each prime number. If you are familiar with the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), this process is identical.

We require eight colors for each prime number in $V = \{1, 2, \ldots, 20\},$ and we require one final color for Vertex $1$ since $\gcd(1, x) = 1$ for all integers $x$.